# Jquery destroy dialog box after x seconds

Tags: jquery, dialog, destroy

How can I destroy a dialog box after a certaing amount of seconds?????

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $(".dialog-message").dialog({
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
     $(this).dialog('close');
    }
   }
  });
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: Questionmarks aren't pack animals :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
var dialog = $(".dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

setTimeout(function(){
    dialog.dialog('destroy');
},5000); // 5 seconds
});
```

Comment: Above wont work as `dialog` wont be defined in the anonymous function passed to setTimeout

Comment: @azatoth - The function is referencing a variable in the same scope. It will utilize whatever value that variable holds at the point in time when it runs. Would be the same as if you removed the `setTimeout()`, and only had the function.

Comment: @patrick: Hehe, oops. The indentation fooled me; I though the `$(function(){});` ended directly after the creation of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function destroyDialog() {
      $(".dialog-message.").dialog("destroy");
 }

 setTimeout("destroyDialog()", 1000);
```

This does it after 1 second, 1000 milliseconds...

Comment: I would recommend to change the setTimeout here to

    setTimeout(destroyDialog, 1000);

Comment: You added a trailing `.` to your selector, and your function will be called against the global namespace, so `destroyDialog()` would need to be defined globally.